# Best way to share assets like images between projects

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'd like to share some **assets** like **icons** between multiple WinRT projects.

With WPF this was a no-brainer (well almost):

- create a **library project** for the assets
- mark the assets as **resources** to embed them into the generated assembly
- reference the assets project from the other projects
- reference the icons from the XAML code using the somewhat strange "**pack**" URI format.

**What's the best way of sharing them with Windows Runtime?**

Is there such a resource embedding and sharing capability, or any other solution?

If no I guess I could add them to every project with "Copy as link" but I hope there is a clean way.

EDIT: I've started to do it naively like I would in a WPF project:

- I've created a new library project "Assets" and added the image inside as "Content"
- I've referenced this project from my main project

But I can't reference the image with the new URI format:

```
<Image Source="ms-resource://Assets/Files/Mushroom.png"></Image>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about it but take a look at the PCL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @sebagomez Thanks for your answer. But AFAIK PCL is a subset of WinRT, the lowest common denominator with other platforms like .Net, so it will probably support less than a bare WinRT assembly. Moreover remains the question of the best way to embed icons in it and then reference them from other projects...

Comment: I understand... my point is, if you could embed your icons (resources) in a PCL component, you probably could benefit from having them at one place... just a thought

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So finally I got the correct result.

Here is the full process:

- create your library project, add your image and set its **build action** as "**Content**"
- reference the library from your main project

To reference the image itself you must:

- use the **"ms-appx" schema**, not "**ms-resource**" as you might find on Google
- specify an absolute path with **///** not **//**

  <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Mushroom.png">

And above all **don't trust the Visual Studio designer**:

- when you get it right it may not display the image
- when you get it wrong it may display it (from a previous success) but at runtime you'll get nothing!

Hope this helps...

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been searching for this off and on for about a week, playing with different variations you probably tried before finding this solution.

Comment: @DanRicker Glad it was helpful to you :-) Indeed I've tried many things and I've been mislead a lot by the VS designer. :-/

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. Right click on the folder where you want the images (e.g., an Assets folder in the new Project) and the select "Add/Existing Item". Then select the images that you need and be sure to change the "Add" button, to "Add as Link". Done.

Comment: Thanks but this is probably the "Copy as link" solution I wanted to avoid for one similar to WPF assets libraries. :)